# Using Putty to redirect input to another host:port

Tags: tcp, telnet, putty, forwarding, packet-sniffers

I have a device that I connect to with Putty(telnet) & after I connect, I get a constant stream of data packets from the device to the putty terminal window. (See handshake diagram)

Is there a way I can take these packets (or the data with a timestamp) and forward them to another host:port that a logging server resides on? I am using Kepware KEPServerEX 5 for the data logging. (See Data Flow diagram)

Alternatively is there a way to log the data from the packets received from the device to a DB without the dedicated logging server?

Note: At this time, all of the devices on the data flow diagram are separate machines/IP addresses.

[image: Data Flow]

[image: Handshake]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a handy tool called RealTerm that initiates a telnet session and has an echo feature that echo's any packet received to a ip:port I choose.